# Somehow the code inside the if statement runs even when the condition is false

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, if-statement, numpy-ndarray

Here I have a function:

```
def check_similarity(bit_pos_array):
    for i, bit_pos in enumerate(bit_pos_array):
        for j, other_bit_pos in enumerate(bit_pos_array):
            if i == j:
                continue
            not_similar = (False in (bit_pos == other_bit_pos))
            if not not_similar:
                print('not_similar : ',not_similar)
                raise Exception('holy crap they are the same', i, ' ', j)
    return False
```

It's input is a 2D numpy array of floats, it should return False if none of the arrays are similar to each other (have the exact same values in the exact same indexes) and raise an Exception if any similar ones are found. When I add a breakpoint inside the if statement, 'not_similar' is True (valid) but the code inside it still runs, the exception is raised but the print statement is not executed. when I do not have a breakpoint inside, then the print statement is executed and the value printed is False (not valid), and the exception is raised. What could cause this weird behavior?

I tried to switch from enumerate to range, and mess with the contents of the loop, but I always get this weird behavior.

when debugging, I can see that even when the exception is raised, the values in the arrays are in fact not the same

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking a double negative scenario here, which affected your logic.

```
not_similar = (False in (bit_pos == other_bit_pos))
if not not_similar
```

If the numbers match, the first line will return `True`, whereas, on different values, it will yield `False`, then the conditional is for when numbers should match but `not True` makes it `False`, which is causing it to skip when numbers match, but run when they don't.

Updated your code to fix the condition, and optimized your loops as well:

```
def check_similarity(bit_pos_array):
    for i, bit_pos in enumerate(bit_pos_array):
        print(bit_pos_array, bit_pos_array[i+1:])
        for j, other_bit_pos in enumerate(bit_pos_array[i+1:]):
            if bit_pos == other_bit_pos:
                print('Similar : ', True)
                raise Exception(f'holy crap they are the same at {i} and {j+i+1}, with number {bit_pos}')
    
    return False

print(check_similarity([1, 2, 3, 1]))
```

Output:

```
Exception: holy crap they are the same at 0 and 3, with number 1
```